# Image adjustment not fixed to position when Text comes in two lines in TileView SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, cardview

I have created a CardView/Tile view to display as a two column. I have calculated the cardView width and height according to screen size of different devices.

The problem I am facing is adjustment of Image. I also have a text just below to Image.
Overall Image is fixed to its position but whenever text comes in two lines `limitline(2)` the image little move to upward (top) position. I set aspect ratio but its not working properly.

Please help me out what I am doing wrong exactly. Can I set image according to screen size as I did for Card/Tile view? It picture you can see first tile image is moved up side.

**Code**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TileView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: CartViewModel
    
    // MARK: - Constants
    private struct ViewConstants {
        static let screenWidth = Constants.DeviceConfig.screenWidth
        static let cardRatio = 133.0/148.0
        static let cardWidth = screenWidth / 2 - 24
        static let cardHeight = cardWidth/cardRatio
        
        static let imageWidth: CGFloat = 106
        static let imageHeight: CGFloat = 106
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Image(viewModel.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(height: ViewConstants.imageHeight)
                
                Text(viewModel.title)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }
            .frame(width: ViewConstants.cardWidth, height: ViewConstants.cardHeight)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

**Image**:
[image: TileView]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the `VStack` with the image and the text has more height when the text goes over two lines.

You are setting a frame on the `VStack` like this:

```swift
.frame(width: ViewConstants.cardWidth, height: ViewConstants.cardHeight)
```

The alignment here is the default of `.center`, so the middle of the `VStack` is vertically centered. This means, when there are two lines of text, the image is going to be a little higher than when there is only one line.

Here are some ways to fix:

**1. Apply a minimum height to the text**

By setting a minimum height on the text, you can make sure it always occupies enough space to extend over two lines:

```swift
Text(viewModel.title)
    .lineLimit(2)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    .frame(minHeight: 40, alignment: .top) // <- HERE
```

**2. Use hidden text to establish the footprint**

If you don't like using a fixed minimum height, then you can determine the minimum height needed by using some hidden text. Then you can show your actual (visible) text in an overlay:

```swift
Text(".\n.")
    .hidden()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
        Text(viewModel.title)
            .lineLimit(2)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    }
```

The hidden text consists of a dot, a newline character and another dot. This is sufficient for finding the height needed for two lines of text.

**3. Align to the top of the frame**

If the height of the tile is fixed (which it appears to be) then you could decide what space you want between the top of the tile and the image and apply this as top padding to the image. Then you can use `.top` alignment when you set the frame on the `VStack`:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 8) {
    Image(...)
        // other modifiers as before
        .padding(.top, 20) // <- ADDED

    Text(...)
        // other modifiers as before
}
.frame(width: ViewConstants.cardWidth, height: ViewConstants.cardHeight, alignment: .top) // alignment added
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

*EDIT* So you said in a comment that the spacing between the text and the bottom of the tile should be 20. This can be defined using padding. Here is how you can use a combination of techniques 1 + 3 to use all the space available with spaces of 20 above and below:

- Instead of setting a fixed size on the Image, apply `maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity` so that it can use all of the space available inside the frame of the `VStack`.
- If this makes the Image too big, you can still add padding to it.
- Apply a minimum height to the text (as per technique 1 above). Alternatively, use technique 2.
- Apply bottom padding of 20 to the text.
- Apply top padding of 20 to the Image (as per technique 3 above).

```swift
Image(viewModel.image)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .padding(.horizontal) // if needed
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .padding(.top, 20)
Text(viewModel.title)
    .lineLimit(2)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .frame(minHeight: 40, alignment: .top)
    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    .padding(.bottom, 20)
```

Comment: First of all thank you. But whats about Image frame how can I resize according to screen sizes. '.frame(height: ViewConstants.imageHeight)' if i remove this line the image is more in big and text more to bottom side. Because text must have bottom spacing 20.

Comment: @IOSTech If you set a frame on the Image then you are defining the size in which it should fit. So if you want it to have the same size on different screens then set a fixed size, if you want it to grow with the screen size then set a size that is proportional to the screen size. Of course, since it is scaled to fit, the width may be the constraining factor too, not just the height. Another way to do it is to omit the frame on the Image and let it use the space available inside the surrounding frame (on the VStack). You can constrain it to use less space by applying padding around the image.

Comment: @IOSTech Answer updated with a new suggestion that combines some of the techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Spacer` with top padding in VStack to push image and text upwards.

```
VStack(spacing: 8) {
    Image(systemName: "photo")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(height: ViewConstants.imageHeight)
        .padding(.top, 30) // Added

    Text("A multi line text. A multi line text")
        .lineLimit(2)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)

    Spacer() // Added
}
```